# how to version and organize routers restify

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, restify

I am new to the javascript world and I am trying to create a 'basic' RESTful application. So far, I've found the restify framework which seems to be one of the best to accomplish this task since Express is more headed to handle the view side of the app too.

What I am facing now is.. how can I version my API and at the same time have the different routes in their own files?

For example:

```
GET - app.com/v1/users
POST - app.com/v1/users
PUT - app.com/v1/users
DELETE - app.com/v1/users

GET - app.com/v2/users
POST - app.com/v2/users
PUT - app.com/v2/users
DELETE - app.com/v2/users
```

I am guessing that for a better organisation, I should have a route file for the v1 and v2 user router version. Something like this:

```
routes/v1/users (will handle the four REST verbs for v1)

routes/v2/users (will handle the four REST verbs for v2)
```

Is this a good approach? How can I achieve that with restify?

I've found [restify-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-router) which seems to solve that problem, but it does not have any commits since March..

In summary..

1- How should I handle multiple routes versions?

2- Is it possible to organise routes in different folders/files?

3- If it's not achievable. Is there any other better framework to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to have a completely separate router for each version of the API?  A lot of this depends upon how you want to manage the code for different versions.

Comment: A separate file / folder for different versions of your API is a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restify has a [nice convention for versioning your Routes](http://restify.com/docs/home/#versioned-routes)

Instead of using the path to determine the version of a route you can require the client to set the version number in the `Accept-Version` header of your request.

I generally create one file per resource and cater for each version of that resource from the same file. Restify has a nice way to define routes with version numbers as shown below:

```
server.use(restify.authorizationParser())

server.get({path: users, version: 1.0.0}, function(req, res, next) {

  // handle version 1 get users request

  next()

})

server.get({path: users, version: 2.0.0}, function(req, res, next) {

  // handle version 2 get users request

  next()

})
```